# pure Domain Driven Design in PHP project

Tags: php, symfony, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

In "PHP World" there is a weird feeling about infrastructure layer in any DDD application (example) what I could found.

I see many examples, when developers using `Doctrine2` in infrastructure layer, use Domain entities (from Domain layer) as `Doctrine2` models, puting doc comments on top on it, or mention them in config (xml, yml).
For instance, [Big Blue Book example](https://github.com/codeliner/php-ddd-cargo-sample), this is where domain entities are located: https://github.com/codeliner/php-ddd-cargo-sample/tree/master/CargoBackend/src/Model, and as you can see it's highly coupled with Doctrine (look on annotations). Are they ?

I've feeling that this is wrong way.

What I understood about DDD, is:
Repository should make a query to persistence layer and pass result to factory to instantiate `Aggregate Root` entity (Domain model) properly. It means that only Factory knows how specific Aggregate Root might be instantiated, moreover there is a, so called, entities lyfe cycle. It means that not every time Domain entity should be instantiated (hydrated) via `__construct`.

If I have correct feeling, then where is a good example, of proper usage `Doctrine2` in DDD-like application?

Answer (score 2):

Tbh I don't completely understand your question, but I will try my best to answer it.

### ORM in Domain Layer

`ORM is best way to easily map your domain objects to your database layer.`The fact, that it use your domain model doesn't make it coupled to your aggregates and entites. `People are scared`, that they need to have clean domain layer, that's is way people like to map their domain layer by xml, yml. I would say `feel free to map it by annotations`, if you're sure, that `you're not going to change orm framework in the future`. That will help developers, which come on your place, change the mapping easily. And in PHP you can be sure, that doctrine will be #1 for long time, so feel free to use it.

But be careful about using ActiveRecord, because it truly couples you with framework. If you don't want to use ORM, you need to go with clean sql mapping. If you have complicated domain good luck with that :)

### Don't be scared of coupling

If you have feeling that `PHP lack features` and they should be build in native php, feel free to use them directly in your model. For example I am using Doctrine ArrayCollection as part of my model, because, if I would use Java for example I would have Collections types directly in the language. It's just that `PHP is retarded with some features` and we need to help it a bit ;)
Same about frameworks, which you would probably implement in domain layer anyway, for example Broadway for event sourcing.

### Don't fight your framework

Sometimes you will find, that framework, which you use for example ORM one, doesn't let you to do things, like you would want it to. You have picked framework and if you don't want to change it, don't fight it. You need to accepted it with all it's advantages and disadvantages.

### Read Red Book by Vaughn Vernon

I see that you don't understand building blocks very well.
Factory is responsible for constructing object at the beginning of their life cycle.
Repository is responsible for saving the state and retrieving it from database. 
You should start with Red Book first, it has a lot of examples. I would call it much more friendly for the DDD beginners than Blue Book.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From what I'm reading (it's a blue and red books in mixin) Factory will be good, not only for beginning of their life cycle. but for restoring entities as well. I also use `ArrayCollection` and this is don't make me more scared. For me the main question what other "worlds" uses :) `C#`, `Java`. Do they use Domain entities as an ORM models in NHibernate, EntityFramework?

Comment: As long as you map your model with ORM, use your factory only for creating new objects. It would has no point to retrieve domain object from ORM via Repository and then push it to factory. ORM will rebuild your whole aggregate, so what you want to push to the factory? :)
Java users use ORM also and if it is important for you, Doctrine is based on Hibernate.  Check out this project: https://github.com/BottegaIT/ddd-leaven-v2

Comment: just to clarify, I have a Domain Model, it requires some specific data as an object(s) from another table(s) in constructor method. Will Doctrine inject all those dependencies ?

Why do I need factory? because Repository should not know how to build entity object. It's not a Repository responsibility. P.S. I'm talking about Collection-Oriented repositories.

Comment: So what's the repository responsibility then? :) Repository should hide persistence layer for your domain layer. It should return aggregates and save aggregates, but not construct them at the beginning of their life cycle. If you're not using ORM, you would probably retrieve data from database and push it to the some kind of reconstructing factory, but we are talking about ORM here, right? :) Will doctrine handle aggregate, which has collection of entites? It's a common problem in relational databases. I won' talk about it here, because it's a subject for another topic.

Comment: Everything you will need to know about ORM mapping is here https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php.

Comment: In the beginning of the Domain model life cycle there is no sense to call repository, but after you called factory to get entity (in the beginning of the life cycle), you have to call repository to keep in it (kinda: ->add()) and repository will handle keeping it in persistence layer.

Comment: Yes, with one exception not ->add, but more like ->save. You're saving state of your aggregate, not adding it. Add makes you think, that whenever you call add(aggregate), within same aggregate it will add new one to your persistence layer, but that's not true. 
Mostly Repository would have two methods: save(Aggregate), load(AggregateID).

Comment: @Edit factory would have create() method not get(), you're not retrieving anything from your factory, you're creating new object there.

Comment: @Dariss The reason for not using annotations is not to be able to swap the persistence framework, it's to avoid adding additional cognitive load into the domain. Someone looking at the code shouldn't have to deal with those persistence annotations. Another valid reason is that annotations may hinder unit testing. It's much better to define mappings outside domain objects and the cost to do it is pretty much the same.

Comment: @plalx I agree. It's totally valid to hide it in your xml, yml. But as long as your whole company use annotations and developers are used to such kind of mapping I would stick with it in domain layer also. It doesn't mess your domain, if people are used to read it. :)

Comment: @Dariss but wait, calling either `add` or `save` or `store` we should not make INSERT call to DB. We should use UoW and it should handle it via flush/commit

Comment: @Dariss "Probably the most important distinction about repositories is that they represent collections of entities. They do not represent database storage or caching or any number of technical concerns. Repositories represent collections."